# Cannot find Injectable name in Ionic 2

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a Ionic app with a single view and a provider to handle the API calls. This view would only display content from the API.
When I run Ionic serve, I get this TS error : `Cannot find name 'ApiService'.`
My IDE is PHPStorm, and when I click on ApiService in the constructor (which is in red and saying cannot find that name), it redirects me to the declaration in the right file.
I have a very simple code with a view component :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from "ionic-angular";
import { ApiService } from "api-test"; // This is the class I have trouble with

@Component({
    selector: 'cgu',
    templateUrl: 'cgu.html'
})
export class cguView {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private apiService: ApiService) {}

}
```

And the code of the ApiService :

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
    API_URL;
    data;

    constructor(public http: Http) {
        this.API_URL = "myapi";
        this.data = {};
    }


    call(action, entity, params) {
        var link = this.API_URL;
        var data = JSON.stringify({mydata});

        this.http.post(link, data)
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.data.response = data;
                console.log(data);
            }, error => {
                console.log("erreur!");
            });
    }

}
```

What am I missing ? The path is right ( I put it in the same folder to be sure..).Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: what is api-test?

Comment: it was the api-test.js file

Comment: you mean '.ts' file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The path is right ( I put it in the same folder to be sure..)

No its not.
When you give path as `"api-test"` it checks in `node_modules` for the package.

You need to give as:

```
import { ApiService } from "./api-test";
```